# SMD identification (marked VS, VA, TF)

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

Can anyone help identify these SMDs? I believe they are regulators, but I need more info so I can replace them.

[image: Image of SMD components]

They are only marked with VS, VA, and TF.

[image: Overview, opposite side of PCB]

[image: Closeup of device sticker]

[image: Overview, same side of PCB]

Comment: What is the device these are part of? Do you have another image showing the board in wider context. A lot of clues can be obtained by knowing surrounding design and purpose.

Comment: It's an embedded PC it's an obsolete device alitle bit old since 2006 I belive

Comment: The large VIA chip is a southbridge chipset. It appears Lippert Embedded may [now be owned by](https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/adlink-technology-and-lippert-embedded-computers-anticipate-majority-position-in-modular-computing-market-144356885.html) [ADLink](https://www.adlinktech.com/). If you can provide the part number for the Analog Devices 16-pin IC near the components of interest, that could also be useful to someone familiar with these.

Comment: @basil can you provide dimensions for the parts?

Answer (score 0):

The markings match with Nexperia 74LVC and 74HCT-series logic devices.

- VS = [74LVC1G07G](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_Nexperia-74LVC1G07GW-125_C282345.pdf) Non-inverting buffer [image]
- VA = [74LVC1G00G](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_Nexperia-74LVC1G00GW-125_C12508.pdf) NAND gate [image]
- TF = [74HCT1G14GW](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2007022237_Nexperia-74HCT1G14GW-Q100H_C547453.pdf) Inverting Schmitt trigger [image]

The marking style of all these parts are similar, here the 74HCT1G14GW as example:

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Inverters_Nexperia-74HCT1G14GW-Q100H_C547453.html))